# Converting a column containing different data to multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a table which was imported from an excel sheet. I am fairly new to advanced SQL.

The first column (Account Number)contains Account Number, Account Date and Name corresponding to the first 3 rows of that column, in that order. The next 3 rows for that column contains the same type of information for different user.

The second column (Amount) contains Amount, Percentage Increase, Amount Due  which correspond to the next 3 rows for that column and so on.

Imported Current table structure:
[image: Imported table]

I would like to know how I can pivot these values into a different table with the structure: 
Account Number, Account Date,Name, Amount, Percentage Increase, Amount Due.

Expected Output Table:

[image: Expected table]

I have tried using cross apply but I have not been successful doing that. 
I have also tried using PIVOT in SQL Server. However, the examples and solutions I came across have columns containing the same kind of data.

```
SELECT [Account Number] FROM SourceTable    AS T1
PIVOT
(
    -- AGGREGATE FUNCTION
FOR
[Account Number]
    IN ( [Account Number],[Date], [Name] )
)
AS T2
```

Kindly let me know how to proceed with this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need more details here as this is pretty vague. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I apologize for that. I will update my question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: I saw for a brief moment you posted your sample data as text instead of an image. That would be much better. Here is the challenge I see. You don't have anything in your table to indicate order so you have no of knowing these three rows are part of one logical set of information. By definition a table is an unordered set. If you included even an identity column you could at least determine which rows go together albeit rather brittle. Without an ordering column this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I can include an Identity column in my source table. How do I proceed from there ?

Comment: @SeanLange Can you find a way to answer this Q? _FlyOnTheAir_

Comment: @Sami not sure what you mean by FlyOnTheAir but I did provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a truly horrible data structure to say the least. You have three rows that need to become a single row. This is ugly at best. Even worse is you have to store everything as varchar at least initially because you have all sorts of datatypes spread out. You can use some conditional aggregation here. The first step is to have sample data in a format we can use.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    SomethingID int identity
    , SomeValue varchar(50)
    , SomeOtherValue int
)

insert #Something values
('1111', 10000)
, ('10/31/2017', 1)
, ('John Smith', 100)
, ('2222', 20000)
, ('10/31/2017', 1)
, ('Jane Doe', 200)
;
```

Now we have to get a little bit tricky. I broke this into multiple steps so you can see what is going on. The first step is to assign a group number to each set of three rows. Then we need to renumber each row within each group so we know which row in the group a given row belongs to. This is why it is so critical to have an ordering column. Then the last step is to use conditional aggregation to parse this disaster into the columns you want.

```
with SortedValues as
(
    select *
        , row_number() over(order by SomethingID) as RowNum
        , case SomethingID % 3 when 1 then (SomethingID + 2) / 3
                when 2 then (SomethingID + 1) / 3
                when 0 then SomethingID / 3
            end as GroupNumber
    from #Something
)
, GroupedOrdering as
(
    select * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by GroupNumber order by RowNum) as GroupRowNum
    from SortedValues
)

select AccountNumber = max(case when GroupRowNum = 1 then SomeValue end)
    , MyDate = max(case when GroupRowNum = 2 then SomeValue end)
    , AccountName = max(case when GroupRowNum = 3 then SomeValue end)
    , Amount = max(case when GroupRowNum = 1 then SomeOtherValue end)
    , MyPercentage = max(case when GroupRowNum = 2 then SomeOtherValue end)
    , AmountDue = max(case when GroupRowNum = 3 then SomeOtherValue end)
from GroupedOrdering
group by GroupNumber
```

I would recommend changing this table structure if at all possible because this is a nightmare to work with. And you still have some work to do here because the datatypes are all over the place. Hopefully this gets this close enough that you can finish this.

Comment: Thank you. This is of great help. I know the data is very ugly and difficult to convert. I shall try your solution and update the results at the earliest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I grouped them as suggested and then imported rows for  account number, date and Name into 3 separate tables.Then, I inserted the account numbers into my final table and updated the rest of the fields based on group Id.